# Convex optimization, java

Tags: java, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I'm looking for a Java library to solve this problem:

[image]

We know X is sparse(most of it's entries are zero), so X can be recovered by solving this:

```
   variable X;
   minimize(norm(X,1)+norm(A*X - Y,2));
```

It's a MATLAB code, matrix A and vector Y are known and I want the best X.

I saw JOptimizer, but I couldn't use it. (Doesn't have good documentation or examples).

Comment: Are you just trying to solve the feasibility problem Ax=y (more commonly written in optimization as Ax=b), where x is any real number? If so, you just need a linear programming solver. I'll give recommendations in an answer if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks. X actually is a sparse vector which only has less than 10% none zeros (in my problem they are all 1). I want to recover all this 1;

Comment: So to be clear, entries of x are restricted to be either 0 or 1?

Comment: absolutely. and also most of it's entries are zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a reasonably good LP Solver.

#### Possible Java LP Solver Options

1. [Apache Commons (Math) Simplex Solver.](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/linear/SimplexSolver.html)
   [See this blog post.](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-apache-commons-math.html)
2. If you have access to [CPLEX (not-free), its Java API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.html) would work great.
3. Also, you can look into [SuanShu, a Java numerical and statistical library](http://www.numericalmethod.com/javadoc/suanshu/com/numericalmethod/suanshu/optimization/Minimizer.html)
4. **[lpSolve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/Java/docs/api/lpsolve/LpSolve.html)** has a Java wrapper which can do the job.
5. Finally, **[JOptimizer](http://www.joptimizer.com/)** is indeed a good option. Not sure if you looked at [this example](http://www.joptimizer.com/linearProgramming.html).

Hope at least one of those help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you're trying to solve a binary integer program for feasibility

```
Ax = b, x in {0,1}.
```

I'm not completely sure, but it seems that you might be interested in the optimization problem

```
min 1'*x
s.t. Ax = b, x in {0,1}
```

where 1 is a vector of 1's of the same dimension as x.

The feasibility problem may be in practice much easier than the optimization problem - it all depends on a particular A and b.

If you can get a license of either CPLEX or Gurobi (if you're an academic), these are excellent integer programming solvers with good Java API's. If you don't have access to these, [lpsolve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/Java.htm) may be a good option.

As far as I can tell, JOptimizer will not solve your problem since your variables are integers (although I have never used JOptimizer).

Answer (score 0):

To solve convex optimization problems in java you can use the following library https://github.com/erikerlandson/gibbous